# Using Python dictionaries/objects in Velocity/Airspeed

Tags: python, velocity

I'm using the airspeed package to work with Velocity templates (script for existing Java/Velocity project, hence choice of engine). I have modeled the data as dictionaries of custom objects and now I'm trying to figure out how to iterate over them in the Velocity template.

Python code:

```
class Walkthrough:
    def __init__(self, title):
        self.title = title
        self.pages = {}
    def add_page(self, page):
        self.pages[page.number] = page

class Page:
    def __init__(self, title):
        self.title = title

walks = {}
walks['obj_1'] = Walkthrough('Object 1')
walks['obj_2'] = Walkthrough('Object 2')
loader = airspeed.CachingFileLoader("./velocity")
text_template = loader.load_template("text_only.vm")
map = { 'walkthroughs': walks }
text_template.merge(map, loader=loader)
```

Velocity template:

```
<html>
    ...
    #foreach($walk in $walkthroughs)
        <h3>$walk.title</h3>
    #end
    ...
</html>
```

I only get 'obj_1' and 'obj_2', not the associated objects. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the *velocity* engine, but I know that Python yields a list of keys when you do `for k in dictionary`.

Since you're **iterating** on `walks`, it would make more sense if you used a `list` instead of a `dict`.

Comment: Yes, the dictionary was a necessary item for building the set, but at render time, the list should work. Thank you for pointing out the obvious!